# Using a gradle task generate a properties file to be included in a jar before the jar task is executed

Tags: gradle, jar

Before is a snippet of my `build.gradle`, it lists a series of tasks which should ideally be run in the following order:

- `createPropertiesFile`
- `jar`
- `obfuscate`
- `deleteNonObfuscatedJar`
- `deletePropertiesFile`

I need `createPropertiesFile` to run before `jar`, as users are building the `.jar` using `./gradlew jar`.

The problem I'm seeing at the moment is this error:

```
> Could not find method doFirst() for arguments [task ':createAuthenticationPropertiesFile']
on task ':jar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.
```

I've also tried `jar.dependsOn(project.tasks.createAuthenticationPropertiesFile)` but I've seen that `custom.properties` is not included in the generated `.jar` when using `jar.dependsOn`

`build.gradle`:

```
nonObfuscatedJar = 'appNotObfuscated.jar'
task createPropertiesFile << {
    def props = project.file('src/main/resources/custom.properties')
    props << 'prop1=value1'
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    archiveName = "$nonObfuscatedJar"
    from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    from configurations.compileOnly.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
    include '**/*.class'
    include '**/custom.properties'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.bobbyrne01.App'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.txt'
    injars "$libsDir/$nonObfuscatedJar"
    outjars "$libsDir/app.jar"
    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
}

task deleteNonObfuscatedJar (type: Delete) {
    delete "$libsDir/$nonObfuscatedJar"
}

task deletePropertiesFile (type: Delete) {
    delete project.file('src/main/resources/custom.properties')
}

jar.doFirst(project.tasks.createPropertiesFile)
jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)
jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.deleteNonObfuscatedJar)
jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.deletePropertiesFile)
```

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, move the properties file creation to the start of the jar task:

```
jar {
    // Create properties file
    def props = project.file('src/main/resources/custom.properties')
    props << 'prop1=value1'

    // Build jar
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    archiveName = "$nonObfuscatedJar"
    from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    from configurations.compileOnly.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
    include '**/*.class'
    include '**/custom.properties'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.bobbyrne01.App'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: This will create the properties file during *configuration phase*, which should be avoided!